# Recommendation for next Movie Event

Tags: discussion, chat-event, movie-night

Beyond 1984. Beyond 2001. Beyond Love. Beyond Death.

ZARDOZ!

[image]

Comment: Wholly inappropriate! I *like* it!

Comment: Would you like to discuss this in [Science Fiction & Fantasy Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley)?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Maybe we can all discuss movie suggestions in the chat room when the official request for suggestions is issued in 2-3 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

## We'll be making a request for suggestions soon here on Meta....

Please remember to add *Zardoz* as a suggestion!

We intend to have another movie night in the next 2-3 weeks.

Comment: @RobertF : Our next movie night has been [announced](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9479/movie-night-nominate-your-favourite-terrible-comic-book-film) and the theme is comic books --- but please suggest *Zardoz* for future events with a more general theme.